# Linking TFS Pull requests with work items

Tags: git, tfs, workitem, alm

We are looking to use the new Pull request feature in Visual Studio 2013 update 4 for our TFS Git repository.

With the code review feature that was available since Visual studio 2012, each code review request results in creating a new "Code Review Request" type work item, which is quite helpful in reporting, etc. Couldn't find a way of linking work items with Pull Requests. Tried the #workitemId format but didn't work. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't checked the database, but the Process Template has no new Work Item type, which means that Pull Request are (90%) implemented with a DB table. No way to create Work Item Links in this case.

Comment: I thought the project template was independent from version control. I can certainly see the work item type of "Code Review Request" in my team project where the version control type is GIT.

Comment: Some small things depends on TFVC. The link to a Changeset works only for TFVC, in fact there is no Code Review for Git (you use Pull Request but they are a different beast).

Comment: My question was how to associate of work items with Pull Requests. I take it that the answer is no then.

Comment: Did some tests, and the #wi works at the commit level. In other words, if you add the # in the title, the commit is associated with the work item, but there is no association between the Pull request itself and the work item.

Comment: Yes Giulio you are right. we can associate wi with commits but not with pull requests. Thanks for looking into it.